# JSTL expression error with weblogic12C

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, jstl, weblogic12c

Hi All in my JSP I have the below JSTL conditional statment :

```
<c:set var="isString"><%= metric.isString(alertVal) %></c:set>                                                  
<c:when test="${(isString) or (metric.name eq 'something1') or (metric.name eq 'something2')}">
</c:when>
```

Its working fine with tomcat server . But when I try to run the same JSP on weblogic12C server. Its throwing below error:

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP content.jsp:827:42:
```

If I remove the brackets from JSTL conditional statment and change the above code as below then its working fine:

```
<c:set var="isString"><%= metric.isString(alertVal) %></c:set>                                                  
<c:when test="${isString or (metric.name eq 'something1') or (metric.name eq 'something2')}">
</c:when>
```

Can someone help me why this error is coming. Can we do some configuration on weblogic side so I don't have to change my JSP code.